# Dynamic query predicate in spring data couchbase

Tags: spring-data, couchbase

I want to dynamically use the URL query params in a request, to query a couchbase bucket. I can access the params from a `MultiValueMap<String,String>` from my request.

So far I have been able to query just a dynamic param, how can I make this @Query more dynamic? That I could query several params comming from a map.

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE #{#n1ql.filter} AND #{[0]} = $value")
```